# Difference in execution time of first and subsequent tensor evaluations

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have implemented a [relatively simple physics model](https://github.com/azag0/tfmbd/blob/master/tfmbd/tfmbd.py#L30-L101) in tensorflow (one matrix diagonalization, a few matrix inversions, bunch of tensor algebra). The building of the graph (in python) takes 3 seconds. For a typical input, the evaluation takes 10 ms. But there seems to be a penalty on the first evaluation, bringing the evaluation time to 300 ms. (For comparison, an equivalent numpy implementation takes 30 ms.)

What is tensorflow doing in that first run that causes the much larger evaluation time?

Is there a way to initialize those things separately from the tensor evaluation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time a graph is run with specific fetches (and/or feeds), optimization passes run to rewrite the graph (these can be configured to some extent by passing a [RewriterConfig](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/rewriter_config.proto) when constructing your Session). But this is also when allocations happen.

Generally it makes sense to cache the Session (and therefore the allocations and optimized graph), doing a separate warmup call if necessary.